# New Product Link in Action tool bar is Not Available (Order Entity)

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

The issue which I am facing is regarding the Orders, steps are Go to Orders - New - Enter detail on this page and click on Save. Now, click on the Write-In product in detail pane. But, New Product link in Action tool bar is not coming. In order to check this I take the import of ISV.config and Site Map, but I didn't find anything related to it.

Another thing, click on Existing Product in detail pane, here New Product link in Action tool bar is available. When, I click on it, the new page Order Product page is there, but the Product Type radio button Existing or Write In is disabled. For this I check the Form onLoad method, but there is no code for disabling this field.

I checked the Adventure Work cycle organization, the New Product link for Write In in Action tool bar is available and In existing Product radio button is also active.

Can you please help me out over this or is there any way I will make the whole ORDER as New as available after CRM installation means w/o any customization?

Looking forward to hear from you.

Comment: I find one resolution of it. This issue is occuring bcaz Lock Pricing feature is enabled. To unlock pricing, open the Order, click Actions> Use Current Pricing. You will now be able to add write-in items.